# Accessing elements in Polymer 3.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-3.x

Can't call a function. Can't access an element by this.$.id. I can do all of this in Polymer 2.0, but am trying to upgrade to Polymer 3.0.

```
ready() {
    super.ready();

    this.$.login.addEventListener('login', this.login);
    this.$.login.addEventListener('forgot-password', this.forgotPassword);
}

login(e) {
    const username = e.detail.username;
    const password = e.detail.password;

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
        .then(user => {
            // why doesn't this work
            this.getUserFromFirestore(user.uid);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            // why doesn't this work
            this.$.login.error = true;
        });
}

getUserFromFirestore(uid) {
    firestore.collection('users').doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
            let user = doc.data();
            console.log(user.role);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Using Firebase Auth. That's working, but when I go to call my `getUserFromFirestore` function I'm getting a "TypeError: this.getUserFromFirestore is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just guessing ...

Have you tried

```
constructor () {
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
}
```

?

Comment: An alternative approach would be `this.$.login.addEventListener('login', (e) => this.login(e));`